# HashSet equality called with passed object instead of stored item

Tags: java, hashset

In the following code, the output shows `CONTAINS` for each object, whereas commenting out the anonymous object's `equals()` method results in `MISSING`, which leads me to believe the second equality pass (`hashCode()` -> `equals()`) actually calls the equality method of the supplied object instead of the object within the collection being tested.

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Hello", "there", "Qix");
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(strings);

for(final String s : strings)
{
    boolean contains = set.contains(new Object(){
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return s.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    System.out.format("%s: %s\n",
            s,
            contains ? "CONTAINS" : "MISSING");
}
```

Why is this? Is it because the `equals()` method, by principle, should be symmetric between the two objects?

Comment: As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) states: "returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))"

Comment: So it's not entirely clear what you're asking; the HashSet either has to do o.equals(e) or e.equals(o).  And as they should be written to be commutative, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking; the reasoning behind using o.equals(e) as opposed to the inverse. Is there any performance increase or oversight?

Comment: Neither - it should be completely arbitrary which one it is, so they probably just chose one at random. It's only noticeable because you're breaking the equals invariants.

Comment: It should also be noted that `hashCode()` *is* called as a preliminary check in this default implementation of HashSet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HashSet` either has to do `a.equals(b)` or `b.equals(a)`. And as they should be written to be symmetric<sup>*</sup>, it shouldn't matter which it chooses.

But for reference, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) states:

> returns `true` if and only if this set contains an element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`

---

<sub>* See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object).</sub>

Comment: Makes sense. To me, personally, I find it strange they did `o.equals(e)` (`passed.equals(stored)`) since each stored object could have a different method of seeing if the given object is equal, whereas the passed object might not account for each type. However, if it matters at that point, you're using `equals()` for something it wasn't intended to do, and should be using something like a `TreeSet`, am I right?

Comment: @Qix It's not strange, the symmetry of `equals` means that `o.equals(e) == e.equals(o)` so you're free to choose. That's also why most `equals` implementations check `this.getClass() == o.getClass()` to make sure they only consider an object of the *exact same type* as equal. Things get complicated if you consider subclasses: can an object of a subclass equal an object of a superclass? The superclass may consider it equal, but the subclass may not.

Comment: Very true, I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 1):

It's an implementation detail which we shouldnt worry about since it's never said in public API how it uses equals. Like you said it's supposed to be symmetric anyway. If we go into src we'll see that it is really `passedObject.equals(storedObject)`

Answer (score -1):

Becaue AFAIK the default **Object.equals** implementation uses **reference comparison** so it checks if the two references refer to the same object.

Here you are comparing instances of Strings with another custom classe, they can't be equal, whatever the way this is done.

Comment: @Qix: Oops did I miss something :( sorry

Comment: You pass hashCode() because you "cheat" returning your custom implementation that you construct to be the same as the other object hash-code.

Comment: OK :) I'd like to know why somebody -1 it so :(